# Combine multiple arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i need to use some array and match them, actually i found an solution but this is not a perfect solution for me, becose i don't have ever 3($array) how i can use an foreach that print another foreach? :D

actually i used this solution:

```
//options
$array = ["13", "14", "15"];
$tutti = [
    "111" => "13", 
    "222" => "13", 
    "333" => "14", 
    "444" => "14", 
    "555" => "14", 
    "666" => "14", 
    "777" => "15", 
    "888" => "15"
];

$realarray = [];
$n_arrays = count($array); // 3 options

if ($n_arrays > 1) { // there is more of 1 option
    foreach ($tutti as $key => $value) {
        if ($value == $array[0]) {
            foreach ($tutti as $key2 => $value2) {
                if ($value2 != $array[0] && $value2 != $array[2]) {
                    foreach ($tutti as $key3 => $value3) {
                        if ($value3 != $array[0] && $value3 != $array[1]) {
                            echo "$key -> $key2 -> $key3<br>";
                            $realarray[] = "$key,$key2,$key3";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($realarray);
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Add some sample output

Comment: Yes, please provide expected output. And clarify this: "becose i don't have ever 3($array)" what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Try building a new array like this:

```
$new_arr = Array();
foreach($tuttui AS $k => $v){
    $new_arr[$v][] = $k;
}
```

Then check if the $value in the first array is found in the bigger one:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++){
    if(in_array($array[$i], $new_arr[$array[$i]])){
         //Then do whatever you need
    }
}
```